# are there any ways to create an insert statement dynamically in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I want to create an insert statement which columns can be customed.
First, I create a curosr for select column's name which from a customed table. It works well.

```
create or replace procedure PROC_TEST_DATA_INSERT
(tableNameT in varchar2)
as
columnName varchar2(30);
CURSOR C_Columns IS
  select
     COLUMN_NAME from user_tab_columns
      where table_name = tableNameT;
begin
end PROC_TEST_DATA_INSERT;
```

Then, I want to open the cursor and insert into a table which column's name come from the cursor. But it doesn't work

```
create or replace procedure PROC_TEST_DATA_INSERT
(tableNameT in varchar2)
as
columnName varchar2(30);
CURSOR C_Columns IS
  select
     COLUMN_NAME from user_tab_columns
      where table_name = tableNameT;
begin
open C_Columns;
   LOOP
    fetch C_Columns into
          columnName;

    insert into
    output(columnName)
    values(columnName);

    if  C_Columns%notfound then
        exit;
    end if;
  end LOOP;
  close C_Columns;
end PROC_TEST_DATA_INSERT;
```

```
call PROC_TEST_DATA_INSERT('aTableName')
```

Then I got
ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view

Apprently, the question is in the insert statement cause if I change the variable to the concrete column like name, an existing column, it works.

```
insert into
    output(name)
    values(columnName);
```

Are there anyways to create a dynamic insert statement in Oracle, or it's impossible?

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You'll need dynamic SQL for that. However, I don't see the point. No problem in *composing* an INSERT statement, but - which values will you insert into those columns? All NULLs? What with primary keys / NOT NULL columns? Something else? What?

Comment: A more common approach would be to have a separate procedure for each table, or a case statement in the procedure to have a separate insert statement for each table, with appropriate tests for primary key and not null constraints.

Comment: For more than 20 years Oracle PL/SQL has had a cursor FOR LOOP that gets rid of OPEN / FETCH / IF %NOT_FOUND ... / CLOSE. I don't understand why people continue to use the old, verbose and error-prone loop.

Comment: @Code Maybe Maybe we use the same old textbook XD. I will try to replace all old loop with the new for loop. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use dynamic query for this. Dynamic query can be executed by two ways.

1. EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
2. DBMS_SQL.EXECUTE (dynamic_sql_string)- It provides more functionality and control over EXECUTE IMMEDIATE, We can parse the incoming table name and column name.

> ```
> create or replace procedure PROC_TEST_DATA_INSERT (tableNameT in varchar2)
> as
> begin
>     if(tableNameT='table1')then
>           EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Insert Into '|| tableNameT ||' (col1,col2) values(123,''abc'')';
>     end if;
>     
>     if(tableNameT='table2')then
>           EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'Insert Into '|| tableNameT ||' (col1,col2,col3) values(123,''abc'',456)';
>     end if;
> end;
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will give it a try.